# How to add limited items in WordPress menu?

Tags: menus

I want to add only 5 or 6 pages in my footer menu, but won't effect that into other menus like as header menu. Whole things need to do with coding not by using php.ini or .htaccess files.

**Note:** If anyone try to add more than 5 or 6 pages then it will not take without editing the code.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can you describe your question in more detail.

what i understand that if you want to show 4 to 5 fix pages in footer menu then you can do using get_permalinks by page id of that page.something like below. replace page id with your page ids in both get_permalink() and get_the_title().

Example :

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(1); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( 1 ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( 1 ); ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(2); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( 2 ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( 2 ); ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(3); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( 3 ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( 3 ); ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(4); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( 4 ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( 4 ); ?></a></li>
 <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(5); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title( 5 ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( 5 ); ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I want to set limit dynamically not to hard code

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to create a new menu in Appearance > Menus. You can create a new menu, add as many pages as u like in it and call the menu in the footer. This will not affect anything else.

Let me know if you need any more help with this.

Comment: I want to add item limit here. If anyone try to add more that five items then it won't take.